# springboot websocket do not work @Autowired

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, autowired

In this class @Autowired is work

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO; // is NOT null

    @Autowired
    private IArticleService articleService; // is NOT null

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/user").addInterceptors(new HttpHandshakeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

In this class @Autowired is NOT work

```
public class HttpHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

      @Autowired
      private IArticleService articleService; // is null

      @Autowired
      private UserDAO userDAO; // is null

    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception ex) {

    }
```

Maybe this is something like a channel wss?

Comment: You used the `new` keyword within `addInterceptors()` and thus, `HttpHandshakeInterceptor` is not a Spring managed bean. Add `@Component` to the interceptor, autowire it within `WebSocketConfig` and use that autowired field within `addInterceptors()`. More of that is explained within https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Answer (score 2):

Your `HttpHandshakeInterceptor` instance is not managed by Spring (i.e. you are creating your instance with `new`).

You have two options here:

**1. Make `HttpHandshakeInterceptor` Accept Parameters of type `UserDAO` and `IArticleService`**

```
public class HttpHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

      private IArticleService articleService;

      private UserDAO userDAO;

      public HttpHandshakeInterceptor(UserDAO userDAO, IArticleService articleService){
          this.userDAO = userDAO;
          this.articleService = articleService;
      }

    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception ex) {

    }
```

2. Put `@Component` on top of `HttpHandshakeInterceptor`

   ```
   @Component
   public class HttpHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

       @Autowired
       private IArticleService articleService; // is null

       @Autowired
       private UserDAO userDAO; // is null

       public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception ex) {

       }
   }
   ```

and use `@Autowired` in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    private IArticleService articleService;

    @Autowired
    private HttpHandshakeInterceptor interceptor;

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/user").addInterceptors(interceptor);
    }
}
```

You can also achieve what you achieved by `@Component` annotation with a `@Bean` definition in one of your `@Configuration` files.

Additionally, you can also go the route of `@Configurable`, but from what I see, you don't seem to need it at this point.